# Add a plugin function to an appended LI

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins

I'm writing a phonegap/jquery mobile app and I'm using the swipeButton plugin to simulate a swipe to delete action (https://github.com/commadelimited/jquery.swipeButton.js).

However, I'm struggling to attach the plugin function to an appended li.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Heres my code:

```
$('#recordings-list').append('<li data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" class="ui-btn-icon-right ui-li-has-arrow"><a href="#view" class="ui-link-inherit" data-transition="slidefade">'
    + '<p class="ui-li-aside"><strong>' + resultString + '</strong> <br/> <span class="sync-label">' + syncStatus + '</span></p>'
    + '<h3 class="ui-li-heading">' + results.rows.item(i).name + '</h3>'
    + '<p class="ui-li-desc"><strong>' + results.rows.item(i).notes + '</strong></p>'
    + '<p class="ui-li-desc"> ' + results.rows.item(i).description + '</p>'
    + '</a></li>').swipeDelete({
                direction: 'swiperight', // standard jquery mobile event name
                btnLabel: 'Delete',
                btnTheme: 'b',
                btnClass: 'aSwipeBtn',
                click: function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    alert("Swipey McSwipeo");
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you are attaching plugin to `$('#recordings-list')` not the appended `<li>`
You should do it like this:

```
var $li = $('<li data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" class="ui-btn-icon-right ui-li-has-arrow"><a href="#view" class="ui-link-inherit" data-transition="slidefade">'
    + '<p class="ui-li-aside"><strong>' + resultString + '</strong> <br/> <span class="sync-label">' + syncStatus + '</span></p>'
    + '<h3 class="ui-li-heading">' + results.rows.item(i).name + '</h3>'
    + '<p class="ui-li-desc"><strong>' + results.rows.item(i).notes + '</strong></p>'
    + '<p class="ui-li-desc"> ' + results.rows.item(i).description + '</p>'
    + '</a></li>');

$('#recordings-list').append($li);
$li.swipeDelete({
                direction: 'swiperight', // standard jquery mobile event name
                btnLabel: 'Delete',
                btnTheme: 'b',
                btnClass: 'aSwipeBtn',
                click: function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    alert("Swipey McSwipeo");
                }
            });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I've tried your suggestion but the swipe event still isnt being triggered - how can I check if the plugin is being initialised? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code is not working is chaining `swipeDelete` to `append` will invoke the function on the selector that is being appended to, not the new element that is being appended.

You can add a traversal method like `.children('li:last')` to your chain to target the string you just appended as an elememnt object

```
$('#recordings-list').append('<li>....</li>').children('li:last').swipeDelete()
```

As an example of targeting various different elements within one chain consider the following:

```
$(selector).addClass('foo')/* method returns original selector*/
           .parent().css('color','red')/* method returns parent element original selector*/
           .find('p:first').text('test') /*first "p" tag in parent of original selector*/
           .hide() /* still returns first "p" tag" */
           .fadeIn();
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick answer, the append is in a loop and I want the swipeDelete function adding to each appended LI, would your code still work (forgive me I'm still new to JS).

Comment: yes, each pass of the loop will only target the new element just appended

Comment: Thanks, I've tried this but the swipe still isnt working, this is the code I'm using:

`$('#recordings-list').append('<li>...</li>').children('li:last').swipeDelete({              direction: 'swiperight', // standard jquery mobile event name                btnLabel: 'Delete',
btnTheme: 'b',                btnClass: 'aSwipeBtn',
click: function(e){                    e.preventDefault();                  alert("Swipey McSwipeo");              }});`

How can I check if the plugin is being initialised?